# Uploadify with different size limits

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, uploadify

I using this plugin (flash version) to upload files on IE 9 and below. Now I allow all file extensions, but if the file is csv it can be up to 4.5Gb anything else is 500Mb. I looked at the php file but the size validation is not there. Where can I check the file extension and size to make the pertinent comparisons?

Comment: look for php.ini in your apache server.

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: php does not have built-in "per-file-type" size limits. there's one global upload size limit, and it applies to ANY file. php couldn't care less if you're uploading a .csv, a .jpg, .iso, blah blah blah.

Comment: I was talking about "post_max_size" that sets the limit of uploading files to the server. I think that's the problem...

Comment: That is not the problem. That is set high enough to allow what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin have `sizeLimit` option:

```
$('#someID').uploadify({
  ...
  'sizeLimit':1024*1024,//1M
  ...
});
```

In the latest documentation the API is different. It has `fileSizeLimit`

> The maximum size allowed for a file upload.  This value can be a number or string. If it’s a string, it accepts a unit (B, KB, MB, or GB). The default
>       unit is in KB. You can set this value to 0 for no limit.

You can see it here http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filesizelimit/

Comment: yeah but that is global. I need 500mb if not csv else 4.5.Gb

Comment: Just check the file size on the server and return and error if it's invalid. PHP can do that pretty easy. Why do you want that kind of option on uploadify side? It's not the plugin purpose and anyone can fake the file size on client side.

Comment: I though the plugin was doing the check somewhere where I could plugin some code, but I think I will have to do it the server way.

Comment: You better do it on the server... the client side is just for pre-test the user input and return error faster (not hitting the server) but if that input is "valid" you must check it again on server side too!